# Calling a class with an abstract base class from a derived class --safely

Tags: c++

I'd like to call the class `Foo` which has the abstract class `Base` in its ctor. I'd like to be able to call `Foo` from `Derived` which is derived from `Base` and use `Derived`'s overriding methods rather than `Base`'s.

I'm only able to do this by using a raw pointer as indicated. Is there any way to do this without raw pointers? I tried `std::shared_ptr` but the compiler complains about abstract classes. Or perhaps is there a better way?

```
#include <iostream>

class Base {
public:
    Base() {
        std::cout << "Hello from Base." << std::endl;
    }

    virtual void show() const = 0;
};

class Foo {
public:
    explicit Foo(const Base  *s)  { // can I avoid this raw pointer?
        std::cout << "Hello from Foo." << std::endl;
        s->show();
    }
    Base *s;
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    Derived() : Base() {
        std::cout << "Hello from Derived." << std::endl;
        Foo(this);
    }

    void show() const override {
        std::cout << "Hi, I'm Derived::show()." << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    Derived();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

which produces the following output:

```
Hello from Base.
Hello from Derived.
Hello from Foo.
Hi, I'm Derived::show().
```

Comment: What is the desired ownership?

Comment: I'd like Derived to be the owner. I'm using the class Foo as a method. Derived should outlive Foo. (Apologies if that sounded Noobish)

Comment: The question is not really clear. Why do you need `Foo`? You create it in the constructor of `Derived` without using it anywhere? Currently `Derived` has automatic storage duration, so passing a raw pointer to `Foo` would be fine, as `Foo` would not be the object the pointer refers to.

Comment: I left out what Foo actually does for the sake of clarity but let me explain. Foo is essentially a method which will return a data struct after some laborious computation. I'd like Derived to possess additional features to Base but have Foo be able to operate on any class which is Base-like. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: the question is still not clear. Why do you think that a raw pointer is not what you want?

Comment: @t.niese That's a good question. I'm a beginner and I've read around that using raw pointers is best avoided for they can cause memory leaks and strange behaviour. So I'd like SO's view if this is safe and for their critical comments if it isn't quite.

Comment: You probably then should use a good book as a starting point instead of picking random information.  Owning raw pointers and manual resource management (`new`, `delete`)  is considered as something bad, but not raw pointers in general.

Comment: Fair enough. I'll pay heed to your advice.

Comment: You can pass a const reference or a reference to `Base` as parameter of the `Foo` constructor. If you want to store the reference to `Base` in `Foo` (as member variable `s`) you can use member intializer lists to give the member variable `s` its value depending on the constructor parameter (because references can only get an initial value and cannot be reasigned). For pointers and for references you have to make sure that as long as `Foo` lives, `Derive` lives and guarantees that the pointer stays valid. That is e.g. the case, if `Foo` is stored inside `Derived` as local or member variable.

Comment: @Sebastian thanks for the pointers (pun intended)! With regards to your suggestion regarding using a const reference to `Base`, I needed to do `Foo(const Base  &s) : s(const_cast<Base &>(s))`

Comment: Yes, but why was the `const_cast` necessary? If you do not need to write, you can have `const Base& s` as member variable, otherwise you should have a non-const constructor parameter in the first place. `const_cast` is for really exceptional circumstances.

Comment: True. The `const cast` was not required after having declared the member variable constant as well. Thanks again @Sebastian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code can be rewritten with const reference to `Base` as

```
#include <iostream>

class Base {
public:
    Base() {
        std::cout << "Hello from Base." << std::endl;
    }

    virtual void show() const = 0;
};

class Foo {
public:
    explicit Foo(const Base& b) : s(b) { // member initialization list to set s
        std::cout << "Hello from Foo." << std::endl;
        s.show();
    }
    const Base& s;
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    Derived() : Base() {
        std::cout << "Hello from Derived." << std::endl;
        Foo(*this); // the parameter would be the object itself *this, instead of a pointer this
    }

    void show() const override {
        std::cout << "Hi, I'm Derived::show()." << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    Derived();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

A reference should be initialized in a member initializer list of the constructor.

When using a raw pointer or a reference 'Foo' should not own 'Base', i.e. `Foo` is not responsible for destroying `Base` and the lifetime of `Base` should be guaranteed by the owner of `Foo`.
You have to make sure that `Base` (=`Derived` in this case) outlives `Foo`. That is guaranteed, if the `Foo` object is owned by `Derived`, e.g. as member or local variable. Then before `Base`=`Derived` is destroyed, `Foo` is destroyed.

You can use normal references instead of const references, but then the same for the constructor parameter as well as the member variable.

A raw pointer (in comparison to a reference) is idiomatic in cases,

1. where the parameter can also be the `nullptr` instead of a valid object or
2. where the pointer is exchanged with another one during the lifetime of the object.

The first case could be handled by `std::optional` instead, the second one with assignment of a lightweight object ('view'), which basically encapsulates a pointer or a reference.

So very few cases (e.g. low-level code, data-structures or for compatibility with C) are left, where raw pointers would still be used in modern C++. And even in those cases, having a wrapper object, which just stores a reference as member variable, would have the same performance (and in practice also the same memory layout) as raw pointers, but are much more clean and safe to use.

In some cases, you would prefer a raw pointer to `std::optional` for performance reasons, when execution speed or memory size really matters. As alternative, a reference to `nullptr` is not allowed in C++.